# Does anybody know a better way to cool a heatsink that is not a fan?

Tags: heat, heatsink, cooling, water

I am designing a portable distiller powered by the sun. I will be heating the water with a heating coil and then when the water evaporates I will be collecting the stem in a metal tube(not sure what type of tube yet). I need the steam to condense back into the water as fast as I can, so my idea was just to put heatsinks around the tube. I am not sure if that is the best method, should I just put another tube over my steam tube and have a pump push water on the outside of the steam tube? Should I just have two fans one for intake and one for exhaust, or should I just add heat pipes and one smaller 80mm fan? Maybe a 1watt pump, not sure if that will more a lot of water though. Thanks!

Comment: Use a bigger heatsink and make sure to orient it so that natural convection can take place easily.

Comment: you have said nothing about the power ,thermal resistance or materials used. How about a photo?

Comment: People use heatsinks all of the time to cool things down...why doesn't that work for you? Why is it a problem if the heatsink gets hot?

Comment: You want the heatsink to touch as much air as possible. And you want the hot air to be able to go up and cool air to be able to come in. That might mean making a chimney.

Comment: A heat pipe may help to move the heat elswehere, but you still need a heatsink to get rid of it.

Comment: You could dunk the heatsink in a nearby flowing river and let power of the river do the water pumping for a low power solution. Cooling (especially more exotic solutions) can be highly dependent on context and the mechanical circumstances of the circuit, which you have not given us.

Comment: A brick chimney about 60m high would allow the heatsink's own convection currents to create cooling airflow.

Comment: What have you evaluated based on 3 types of heat transfer?

Comment: Anodizing can improve performace of a heatsink by increasing emissivity

Comment: Is your concern about the heatsinking being hot meaning the component is hot? Or is your concern about the heatsink being hazardous because it is hot?

Comment: heat flow is too complex for here. Know that heatsink fin orientation matters; vertical faces are best, tight fins are better than sparse fins (but not too tight), surface area is the most significant criterion, good convection can half thermal resistance over time, a fan _can_ drop it up to 99%.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson If the heatsink gets hot then the steam inside of the tube won't condense as fast. So I am trying to figure out a lower power solution to this issue. I just wanted to know if there was something better than fans.

Comment: @DKNguyen When the heatsink gets hot then the transfer of heat won't be as strong and the steam inside of the tube won't turn back into the water.

Comment: I want to clarify I am distilling water in a portable machine. I am using a coil to heat the water and I will trap all that steam in a metal tube and surround the metal tube with heatsinks for faster condensation. I was just wondering if there was a better way to cool the heatsinks.

Comment: @RahulVijayan You might almost be better making a very long coil of thin copper tubing (I am not sure if it would better if there was a small gap between the coils or if they are up against each other) so there is maximum surface area. I think that would be more effective than sticking heatsink around a tube. since the heatsinks do little for the steam in the center of the tube, and placing heatsinks around the tube just eats up space that you could use to fill with more thinner tube to get maximum surface area for the steam.

Comment: I don't think you understand how heat sinks work. The heat sink **must** get hotter than the surrounding air (or water or oil or whatever) in order to dissipate the heat.

Comment: @DKNguyen But if we have a heatsink be the best for cooling the steam? Also, won't the water tater weird if it is in a copper tube?

Comment: @RahulVijayan Is your goal to waste space with heatsinks or is your goal to increase the surface area with which to get heat out of the steam and into the air? If not copper what were you planning to use? Copper tube is easy to coil and is used for water pipes for a long time, but you should look into it and judge for yourself the behaviour of copper plumbing.

Comment: @DKNguyen I did not know about the copper tubing thank you for the clarification. The reason I want to use the heatsink is it will in my understanding cool the actual steam inside the cooper tube, thus leading to the steam to condense back into wat. I will then collect this water to drink. So I just want to cool the steam in the pipes as efficiently as possible.

Comment: @RahulVijayan Usually the thing you want to cool has fixed shape and surface area like an engine or processor, so heatsinks increase that. But you can change the shape of a cloud of steam to increase surface area directly.

Comment: @DKNguyen So how would I do that? right now I am thinking has the copper tube go around in a circle and then have a nozzle at the side of the container, using gravity to release the water into whatever anyone needs it for.

Comment: @RahulVijayanThat sounds about right. I think you would have to pump in the steam from the top and rely on pressure to force it downward through the coil since the water can only fall down so collection has to happen at the bottom. You could experiment with cheaper and easier to work with plastic tubing first and bathe the outside in cold water to make up for plastic's lower thermal conductivity while experimenting.

Comment: @DKNguyen So the design I am thinking it just as the water heats up it will rise s hot air rises. There will be a tiny notch on the top of the container for the steam to go, this notch will be a copper tube. The copper tube will move up and the spiral downward for gravity to take over as the steam condenses to water. With the plastic tube, should I just have the whole chamber filled with water and add a small 1watt pump to just circulate the water?

Comment: @RahulVijayan That's my first stab at how it would look. For plastic tube, I wouldn't bother circulating. It's just a test so you get experience so just submerge a small collection tank along with coiled tube in a bucket of ice water. Seems way too much effort to cut and seal a hole at the bottom of bucket to run collection tank out of the bucket.

Comment: @DKNguyen but won't the water get hot after some time and then slow down the process?

Comment: @rahul It's just a test so you can find issues before working expensive copper tube so that's okay. Just add more ice or something.

Comment: **This is not an Electrical question, this is pure physics.** Best way of thermal transfer is conduction; best conduction depends on the number of molecules that makes contact with the hot surface. A fan blows air (a gas) in the hot surface. But if, instead of a gas, you use a liquid for cooling, there will be more thermal conduction. This is the reason why water is used for cooling computer's processors, and why a mix of water and monoethyl glycol is used to cool a car's engine. So, there are other best ways of cooling than a fan. Usually, all liquor distillers runs their pipes through water.

Comment: Ask this on a engineering or mechanical stack exchange.

Comment: @DKNguyen I would like to sell this at some point to people, this is why I want to have it all built it. Maybe I could water cool the tube with a small 1-watt pump and a fan and a rad. and I could just use coolant from PC parts and use plastic so it does not get corroded.

Comment: @RahulVijayan Plastic would be real bad to use. It is just cheap and easy so good for tests. It is so bad you need to submerge in water rather than use air to make up for how bad it is. Definitely can't sell that.

Comment: @DKNguyen what do you think I should do then? copper tube and a fan for air cooling, or cooper tube and a heatsink or Heatpipe or both, or should I water cool the pipe?

Comment: @RahulVijayan Sure, water cool the pipe if it's practical But I do not know if this is for use in a desert, home, or portable where you can spare water, weight, and power. Doesn't hurt to toss a fan on because you can always just not turn on the fan. Heatsinks are a waste of space here IMO unless you go with a full blown heat exchanger.

Comment: @DKNguyen so you think no heatsink and just a fan. As that is easier and can be used for everyone. the only issue is it will be loud. Should I go one or two fans?

Comment: @RahulVijayan That would be specific to your setup.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111002/discussion-on-question-by-rahul-vijayan-does-anybody-know-a-better-way-to-cool-a).

Answer (score 1):

"Cooling" is the transfer of heat from an area of higher heat to one of lower heat. Transferring the heat of your tube to a heat sink is only one step, you then have to transfer the heat of the heat sink to something else. Air works, but if the air is not moving, it acts like an insulator. Think of what insulation is doing in your walls; is is trapping air so that it cannot move, so heat becomes trapped in it. So all the fan is doing is ASSISTING the heat in getting OUT of the heat sink. You can do it without fans, IF you have enough surface area in the heat sink to allow for natural convection to remove the heat. But there are limits to this too, because while the heat is moving THROUGH the heat sinks to the fins in order to radiate and dissipate into the air, it might be building up in the immediate junction area with your device to the point of causing damage. So the fans accelerate that movement of heat for you in order to avoid that. But depending on the ambient conditions, the amount of heat created, the surface area of the heat sink and the availability of convection flow, you may not need fans.